# If a certain user views a certain page do an action

Tags: php, database, wordpress, string

Im trying to make a competition for a wordpress website where a user is randomly selected daily and gets a meta value added to there meta_data for instance "Today" or "winner".

What im looking for is the best way to check if the winning user has viewed the winning (claim) page.

Im open to any way of doing this and the ways I can think of are:

- Match the user meta data to something in the url to see if it matches
- Match the users meta data to perhaps some kinda content or serial number on the page and see if it matches.

Can anyone suggest the best / cleanest and most maintainable way to do this please.

Can be done with php.

Any help would be greately appreciated.

Many thanks

David

Answer (score 0):

If your application requires knowing when a specific user opens a specific page, your best approach might be to write an `onLoad()` function in PHP and call it at the top of every relevant script. It would be a centralized place where you can do all checks of this type.

In the DB you could have a table `user_visit_notifications` where you store:

```
user_id | page_url          | visited | time_visit
1234    | /path/to/page.php |         |
```

Store all the visitors you want to watch.  Then in `onLoad()`, execute code similar to below (probably best to factor it out into a separate function that `onLoad` will call:

```
public function onLoad(){
  // Get all records concerning this user that have not been processed
  // SELECT * from user_visit_notifications WHERE user_id = ? AND visited = NULL
  $user_visits = $db->fetch_all(...); 

  /* TODO: process records: eg: send admin email and set visited and time_visit */
}
```